# Scala IDE for eclipse: Any way to "quickfix" imports?

Tags: eclipse, scala, import, ide

For Java, in the editor of a class, I am used to hovering over an unknown class to bring up the quickfix menu which suggests imports to resolve the problem quickly.

Is there any such feature in the Scala IDE for eclipse? Hovering over an unknown class in a scala file does not bring up anything for me, so I end up typing imports manully. That is pretty annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a mac: `CMD+shift+O` adds imports as necessary and putting the cursor on a class name and doing `CMD+1` does it for that one thing.  Non-mac I'm sure has similar.

Comment: do you happen to know if there's also a way to create classes that don't exist yet, when they are already referenced in code? Also I wonder if it is somehow possible to click through to a class's implementation (like for Java holding down CTRL + Click)?